# How to rewrite query url to existing prettier url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

What is the syntax to rewrite this

http://www.example.com/cart/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=8&products_id=22

to this? http://www.example.com/class-registration

Note: RewriteBase has to be / because other rules depend on it. It's a joomla 1.5 site. Please don't answer that I can use a component.

(repost from serverfault, realized mod rewrite q's don't get answered much there)

Comment: I will ask the same question as there: **Show what you have got so far**. + Cross post within 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^class-registration$ index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=8&products_id=22`

Comment: Didn't _motorcycle_school_ ask for the opposite rule?

Comment: The way it's worded, maybe... But I am pretty sure what he wants is to be able to access the long query string url using the short url.

Comment: You may be right. Let's wait for him/her to come back (if he/she does).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to append to your .htaccess file to achieve the rewriting:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^main_page\=product_info\&cPath\=8\&products_id\=22$  [NC]
RewriteRule  cart/index.php  /class-registration?  [L,R=301,NE]
```